# Is it manatadatory to use Finder Methods in service.xml file to retrieve Data from tables

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay-6 and I am a beginner at it.

My requirement is that, I have a table named **Players** with columns as `ID`, `Name` and `Category` from which I need to retrieve all the Player-names based on `Category` selected from Front-end.

I know that I need to use Liferay's `ServiceBuilder` for this, so my question is while creating a `service.xml` file do I need to use finder methods for this or I can manage without that?

Please specify, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Preethi, you don't *need* to use Liferay ServiceBuilder, but doing so would save you a great deal of time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use finder-methods, but if you are anyways using `ServiceBuilder` than I don't see any point not taking advantage of the finder-methods. It is just a matter of writing few lines in the `service.xml` something like this:

```
<finder name="Category" return-type="Collection">
    <finder-column name="category" case-sensitive="false" />
</finder>
```

But if you are not at all using `service.xml` than ofcourse you can't use finder methods and you have to do everything manually.

But if you are using `service.xml` or are planning to use `service.xml` then by all means use finder-methods, since it would save you a day's work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're determined to use the Service Builder, I agree that Finders are the best way to do it

1. each Finder in service.xml, will give you access to a playersLocalPersistence.findby.. method, tat will return a Collection of Players
2. If you want to retrieve something else (e. a List playerNames), you can write a method in PlayersLocalServiceImpl, use the above finder function inside the function body, and return your custom Collection, accessible from PlayersLocalServiceUtil
3. the findByPrimary fider is created anyway. e.g if 'ID' is set to be the primary key, you don't deed to add a Finder for that attribute

Practically, you need to write custom Queries, only when you want to search on more than 1 Entities (in other words, the FROM query part, uses more than one database tables). In every other case, a Finder node in service.xml is the way to go